# JavaScript get value or property of an Array of objects if object has that property

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

say I have an array

```
var test = [{a: 26, b:14, c:null},{d:67, e: 8}];
```

say I want the value of c, I don't know what value c will have or which array will have c;

I was thinking of using `$.grep` but it does seem like I could use it in that way

So how do I go about getting the value of c?

**EDIT**

Just test as per my comment you can do

```
$.grep(test,function(e){return e.hasOwnProperty('c')})
```

This will return the array that has the object/objects of the property you want

Comment: Try `test.filter(function(x){return "c" in x}).map(function(x){return x.c}).forEach(alert)` - or, with jQuery, `$.each($.map($.grep(test, function(x){return "c" in x}), function(x){return x.c}), alert)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to make use of [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    if (test[i].hasOwnProperty('c')) {
        alert(test[i].c); // do something with test[i].c
        break; // assuming there is only ever 1 item called c, once we find it we can break out of the whole loop.
    }
}
```

---

As you suggested, `$.grep` would work too:

```
var objectsThatHaveC = $.grep(test, function(obj) {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty('c');
});

if (objectsThatHaveC.length) {
    alert(objectsThatHaveC[0].c); // assuming there's only 1 object with a 'c', otherwise you'd still have to loop here
}
```

Comment: You missed the closing `)` for `if`. Other than that, this works good.

Comment: out of curiosity how would you go about using grep for this, I was thinking of something like 'var hope = $.grep(test,function(e){return e.c == something})' but can't figure out what that some would be unless you could do 'var hope = $.grep(test,function(e){return e.hasOwnProperty('c')})'

Comment: @SamStephenson Yep, that would do it. You just need it to return true/false for whether to keep that obj or not, so your prediction is spot on. `var objThatHasC = $.grep(test, function(obj) { return obj.hasOwnProperty('c') }); alert(objThatHasC.c);`. Your right, maybe that would be easier than the loop ;-) adding it to my answer.

Comment: Correction – the `$.grep` would return an array, so you'd then need to do `objectsThatHaveC[0].c`. See updated answer.